# Connection failed when i connect from another pc to phpmyadmin since qgis

Tags: mysql, qgis

Hey guys i did a web page in phpmyadmin with mysql database with xamp in windows 10 in my local pc.

So i join my the tables in qgis proyect. I did the conection In local model withou problem.

But I have a second pc in local and i put the same parametres and the user and password from data base, and I only changes "localhost" to ip from my first pc" on is the webpage. So appears the next message:

So , whats wrongs?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to load webpage from another pc using ip??

Comment: _Small Note_ If the ip address starts with `192.168.` its a private network address (not accessible directly from the outside of your network, so you dont need to hide it :)

Comment: _Small Note_ You cannot connect to `phpMyAdmin` as its just an app written in PHP, not a server, MySQL is the server

Comment: yes the web page load in all my pcs in my netwrok and the phpmyadmin too, in qgis no @RiggsFolly

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh ok  sorry so ye is a local level only i need this not external

Comment: @RiggsFolly i can connect it since every local pc putting myiplocal/phpmyadmin its works. because i modified the httpd-xamp.conf putting "Require all granted"